# How to properly open a pdf in a new activity?

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I want to view/open a PDF in another activity without triggering browser or downloading the pdf itself.

Currently I am using this code:

```
String myPdfUrl = "http://example.com/awesome.pdf";
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

However this doesn't seem to be reliable. Sometimes my pdf is loaded, sometimes it is not. Is there a better way to do this?

I was searching for a library which opens a remotely hosted pdf and closest I got was this https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager however it supports only from API 21 whereas I need to support API 19 as well. Also this library seems to just download PDF and open it, instead of just simply displaying it in a webview.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Sometimes it is not." What does this mean?

Comment: Sometime pdf is not loaded and all I see is a blank page with an empty webview. I tested the PDF link and its not an issue.

Comment: Have you tried encoding the PDF URL in URL format? `URLEncoder.encode(myPdfUrl, "UTF-8")`

Comment: Yes this is how I am using it at the moment.

Comment: You aren't in your example.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to view/open a PDF in another activity without triggering browser or downloading the pdf itself

That's not possible, unless you have a Web site that will do the PDF rendering.

> However this doesn't seem to be reliable

I do not believe that it is designed to used that way.

> Is there a better way to do this?

Build your own Web site that does PDF rendering to something (e.g., images), then show that Web site in your `WebView`.

It would be far simpler to download the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

What about this library?

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Android view for displaying PDFs rendered with PdfiumAndroid

Comment: Downloading file in Android is not a big deal. Would you like to save the time and traffic for downloading the large pdf to render it remotely? 
Other words do you need the same as Google Docs is doing for you but the only problem with it is it working not reliably?

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a component based on a Webview to display a PDF file inside an app.

[You can find it here](https://github.com/BrunoAndroidDev/PDFViewer/tree/develop). Hope it would help you

Comment: No, you have to download it

Comment: I want to avoid downloading :/ Displaying pdf in google docs and then showing that in webview works but not all the time :/